# Protection prevention ignores deleted answers from new users

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, deleted-answers, protected-questions

- Related: [Prevent protecting questions under certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances)

  > ...we're considering removing the option to protect from questions that haven't received at least one answer from a [new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user). That's a bit of a no-brainer - **by definition, you can't have new users vandalizing a question with their answers if none of them have posted any answers.**

Above apparently was implemented and deployed today but it doesn't look like working fully as intended. Protect option becomes available when question gets an answer from new user but disappears after deletion of such an answer.

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/184173/31260) was polluted by [this (mod-deleted) answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/312746/31260) from new user but despite this, "protect" option is not available. For comparison, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/310734/31260) has a [not deleted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310831/31260) from a new user and "protect" option *is* available for it.

As far as I understand, questions with deleted answers from new users are expected to have "protect" option available. Rephrasing quoted feature request, that's a bit of a no-brainer - **by definition, you likely have new users vandalizing a question if one of their answers is deleted.**

<kbd>[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQPME.png]</kbd>

<sub>See also: **[The system supports questions with multiple answers poorly (and is becoming worse at it)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7770/31260)**.</sub>

Comment: This renders the whole feature useless, wonder why they didn't test such a major change here on MSE first.

Comment: @ShadowWizard interesting that [the very first comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances#comment894901_276197) to implementation description asked, **"How would existing deleted answers be counted for protection?"** They apparently were in such a hurry to make it even more easier to dump garbage answers at SE that totally ignored it

Comment: Yeah, this is really sad. They took away a useful tool just because some stupid people abused it. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard note how my screen shot shows a workaround for cases when new user gets only one upvote (inexperienced askers tend to vote up any garbage "out of gratitude"). Vote it down so that answerer's on-site rep gets under 10 and after that, protect. One can even undownvote after that - all this can be done  while vote is not yet locked. I wouldn't be surprised if they find a way to close this "awful hole" earlier that fix the bug reported here

Comment: That's hardly "vandalism". Just a _single_ misunderstanding of what answers should be. It's been deleted and that's that; we can all move on. What's the problem?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet consider re-reading the question and taking closer look at screen shot. Protect option is available when answer from new user is not deleted but disappears after deletion (in example at the screen shot, abuse was considered [strong enough to warrant mod deletion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rQPME.png)). "Rephrasing quoted feature request, that's a bit of a no-brainer - by definition, you likely have new users vandalizing a question if one of their answers is deleted."

Comment: I disagree with your "by definition" statement (not the quoted one). "You likely have new users vandalizing your question if one of their answers is deleted." If a new user posts a poor answer, and then self-deletes it,especially after perhaps one single comment, then it's not vandalism, to me.

Comment: @CGCampbell note the word "likely". System considers 15K users trusted enough to judge whether it is the case or not (at least when answer is not deleted)

Comment: While "vandalism" is almost certainly an unnecessary overstatement, a deleted answer from a new user is clearly a stronger indication than a non-deleted answer that a question may need protection, so I agree that it makes no sense to hide the option in this scenario.

Comment: @Ixrec FWIW "vandalizing" is the word used in original feature description, you can find it in the quote that opens this question

Comment: @gnat Now that you mention it I had missed that...tbh I think it's an overstatement there too. More importantly, these comments debating whether it is vandalism or not are not terribly constructive, so let's focus on the actual bug.

Comment: hm implementation seems to be even uglier: as of now, [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/107669/31260) has a non-deleted answer from a user with less than 10 on-site rep but protect option is not available. Looks like they were indeed [in a hurry...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276955/protection-prevention-ignores-deleted-answers-from-new-users#comment897259_276955 "...to make it even more easier to dump garbage answers at SE")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're hurrying out a fix in the next build (rev `2016.3.15.4264` on MSE/MSO, `2016.3.15.3345` on sites)

Comment: thanks. While we're at it, could you please take a look at the issue mentioned in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276955/protection-prevention-ignores-deleted-answers-from-new-users/276981#comment897371_276955)? "question has a non-deleted answer from a user with less than 10 on-site rep but protect option is not available"

Comment: yup yup, we're now excluding the association bonus from the rep check against the [new-user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege in this case

Comment: re-checked troublesome questions - both deleted answers and assoc bonus are now handled as expected, protect option became visible