# Protect privilege has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions

On Puzzling, I noticed first that there wasn't an option to protect my own questions. I brought this up in chat, and other high-rep users replied that it has disappeared for them too.

Not sure if this is just Puzzling, or site wide, but I have just under 16k rep and have had the privilege a while. It's odd it just disappeared. [Users on Literature have reproed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36215949#36215949).

EDIT: It's all questions, including 24 hour old ones with new user answers. [Random example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-to-determine-if-a-rubiks-cube-is-sufficiently-scrambled) that has no protect option for me.

Comment: 15k users are only allowed to protect questions which are 24 hours old and have at least one answer from a new user. We disallowed protecting any question [a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances).

Comment: @animuson this applies for any question. Ones from the beginning of the site with new user answers still don't have the option

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That question has no answers by users that don't have the 10 rep needed to answer a protected question.

Comment: @Servy ok scrap that example. I'll find another

Comment: Doesn't work on other sites either. Codegolf and literature both have repro-ed.

Comment: Curiously SFF hasn't repro-ed: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/155325/timeline

Comment: No users with < 10 rep on these examples.

Comment: here is what you do if you want to protect: 1) vote down [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50184) or [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/9325) answer, so that answerer's rep falls from 111 to 109 2) reload question page in browser 3) observe how protect link appears and use it 4) while still in voting grace period undownvote to preserve your rep (I am not well aware of quality norms at Puzzling but it seems that for second answer it would be fair to keep downvote - it looks like cr@p upvoted only by inexperienced asker out of pure gratitude)

Comment: @randal'thor can you see deleted answer(s) from <10 on-site rep user(s) in [that SFF question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/155325)? if yes then that explains it - deleted answers also enable the option to protect

Comment: @gnat Yes, two deleted answers from a 1-rep user.

Comment: @randal'thor there you go: [Protection prevention ignores deleted answers from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276955/165773), bug reported in May 2016 and fixed almost immediately after that. Deleted answers enable protect option just like regular ones

Comment: typo in [my first comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292762/protect-privilege-has-disappeared?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment951142_292762): should read "answerer's rep falls from 11 to 9" (FWIW 111->109 would work for users with association bonus)

Comment: Looks like the same basic problem as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238594/how-many-questions-escape-community-protection-because-of-reputation-gained-with

Answer (score 3):

15k users are only allowed to protect questions which are 24 hours old and have at least one answer from a [new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user). We disallowed protecting any question [a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances).

Comment: Moved from a comment since this appears to be the answer.

Comment: ... But not worth an upvote :(

Comment: @Iain why not? It's correct,  and answers the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You missed my elipsis and sad face. The original commenter didn't seem fit to upvote the correct answer. I was the first to do so.