# Protecting questions with answers by deleted users

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts, protected-questions

As discussed in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276978/328832), a question must have at least one answer by a user with less than 10 reputation in order to be protected by a 15k+ user.

For example, here’s a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/was-hiro-replacing-himself-when-he-time-traveled?rq=1) that’s several years old  with no answers by low-rep users:

[image]

Clearly there’s no protect option.

The protect option shows up normally on another fairly old [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91636/how-has-galadriel-acquired-evil-mode/139041#139041) with a post or two by a <10 rep user.

[image]

***However*, the protect option is also present on any post whose only answers are by users whose accounts were subsequently deleted**, for example [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/did-peter-ever-save-that-girl?rq=1) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102103/future-time-travel-in-terminator-movies?rq=1), regardless of how much reputation they originally had:

[image]

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: A user who's been deleted doesn't have any rep anymore, so I don't really see the problem; there's a decent chance their account was deleted *because of* the same (sorts of) things that necessitate the protection (like spam).

Comment: @NathanTuggy - There may not be a problem. On the other hand, most sites have a few users with hundreds or thousands of posts who left, and a good fraction of those will have theirs as the only answer. So 15k+ users could protect those if they wanted to, which might go against the purpose of the answer requirement. Newly active questions sometime get a lot of new answers (at least on sites with less turnover in the active queue), so users might be motivated to answer and protect those preemptively.

Comment: Better that than to be unable to protect a question because of a spammer's post. That *has* happened, often enough I think it may have gotten changed explicitly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Then it might not be a bug. There *may* be no easy way to implement both.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect they're just relying on 15kers being *mostly* fairly sensible, and only preventing the worst problems in the software.