# Not possible for 15k+ users to protect or unprotect questions on which a moderator has disabled commenting

Tags: bug, status-completed, protected-questions, comment-lock

Ordinarily, users with 15k+ reputation can protect questions that are at least 24 hours old, and have at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation.

However, I'm unable to protect [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339944/377214), which satisfies both of these criteria: the "protect" button doesn't show up. After eliminating other potential causes, such as:

- the one answer from a <10 rep user being not from a new user, but from an established user who is suspended: protection [should still be possible in this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316149/possible-for-15k-users-to-mark-questions-which-have-been-answered-by-suspended)
- the fact that the question has an active bounty: I've protected questions with bounties before with no problem, and I've only had 15k+ reputation (or even a registered account) after the current criteria were set

...I believe the only remaining reason is the fact that a moderator has disabled commenting. Since, internally, this is still treated as a lock, and locked questions can't ordinarily be answered or protected, the "protect" option doesn't show.

Can it please be made possible for 15k+ users to protect questions on which a moderator has disabled commenting?

**Update:** This also applies for the "unprotect" option as well: there are no restrictions on unprotecting, so the *only possible* reason why the "unprotect" option isn't showing up is because the question is comment-locked.

Comment: It's only a client side check; I don't see the buttons either but with some POST calls I was able to unprotect and reprotect the question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/339944/revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report! I made sure the protected and locked notices played well together, but completely forgot about the menu links.

This is now fixed.